# Positioning ropes equidistantly on a landscape display

Tags: java, android

I would like to render 4 similar ropes in my game that are equidistant on a landscape mode display.

How can I proceed? My screen is 1920*1080, at 420 dpi.

Is there any way that I could link the ropes coordinates with pixels or is there another way?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "equidistantly" here?

Answer (score 1):

I think your screen size will likely vary between phones.

You should use a method to access the screensize.

Probably subtract a buffer (say 200 pixels) from each side of the screen size (e.g. `1920 - 2*200`)

Divide the remainder by 5, as you want 4 ropes (so 5 gaps between them)

---

`B = Buffer , G = Gap, | = Rope`

`B G | G | G | G | G B`

---

Use a `'Screen Space to World Space'` transformation to transform co-ordinates for the rope positions into world space coordinates at which they can be placed.

---

`Rope n Position = BufferSize + n*GapSize`

Comment: Please can you detail how to transfor co ordinates into world space. I only know the x,y coordinate system that starts from the bottom left of the screen.Am I mistaken?

Comment: I found a drawable.setBounds(x,y,a,b) wherd I can set the limits for my renderd image. Is it useful?

Comment: I am not experienced in Java android studio - specific technical advice is something I can't give - I can only help you in terms of suggesting an approach that you might take, as I have done.